# Displaying multiple notifications on status bar

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am developing an application. I want to display multiple notification to status bar area. But every time it's showing previous message. I have tried many things but its not working, how can I display multiple notification in an Android status bar. 
Below is my code :

```
private void Notify(String Title, String Message) 
{

          NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
          Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,Title, System.currentTimeMillis());
          Log.e("NotificationManager","notify"); 
          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NoteEdit.class);
          notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

          Log.e("NotificationManager","notificationIntent");
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          notification.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(), Title,Message, pendingIntent);
          notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
          notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
          notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
          notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
          notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID , notification); 

         }

    }
```

Comment: Just try to set different NOTIFICATION_ID (ex. with Random().nextInt()) for each notification

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're using the deprecated `Notification` method rather than `Notification.Builder`?

Answer (score 0):

use this at place of 0 you will have to use a variable and increment it every time

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),
                index++, notificationIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: this is notification id same as @Gooziec told